# Trying to get C# Dependency Injection example to work

Tags: c#, spring.net

I downloaded this code from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164657.aspx but its VS 2003.  I'm trying to get it to work in VS 2010.  There seems to have been some changes.  For example, I needed to instantiate a resource object in 2010.  Here is the main code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml;
using SpringDIExample;
namespace runner
{
class Class1
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // 1. Open the configuration file and create a new
        //    factory, reading in the object definitions
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead("config.xml"))
        {
            // 2. Create a new object factory
            Spring.Core.IO.InputStreamResource resource = new Spring.Core.IO.InputStreamResource(stream, "config");
            XmlObjectFactory xmlObjectFactory = new XmlObjectFactory(resource);

            // 3. Call my factory class with generic label for the object
            //    that is requested. 
            IDomainObjectInterface domainObjectInterface = (IDomainObjectInterface)xmlObjectFactory.GetObject("DomainObjectImplementationClass");

            // 4. Use the object just like any other concrete class.
            Console.WriteLine("My name is " + domainObjectInterface.Name);
        }



        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
 }
```

It always crashes on this line:

```
XmlObjectFactory xmlObjectFactory = new XmlObjectFactory(resource);
```

Here is Stack Trace:

```
   Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectDefinitionStoreException was unhandled
  Message=Unexpected exception parsing XML document from config
  Source=Spring.Core
  ObjectName=""
  ResourceDescription=""
  StackTrace:
       at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.XmlObjectDefinitionReader.DoLoadObjectDefinitions(Stream stream, IResource resource)
       at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.XmlObjectDefinitionReader.LoadObjectDefinitions(IResource resource)
       at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.XmlObjectFactory..ctor(IResource resource, Boolean caseSensitive, IObjectFactory parentFactory)
       at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.XmlObjectFactory..ctor(IResource resource)
       at runner.Class1.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\dhood\Desktop\SpringExample\TestRunner\ConsoleRunner.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectDefinitionStoreException
       Message=Failed parsing object definition '<object name="DomainObjectImplementationClass" singleton="false" type="ImplementationClass1, SpringDIExample" xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" />'
       Source=Spring.Core
       ObjectName=""
       ResourceDescription=""
       StackTrace:
            at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.DefaultXmlObjectDefinitionParser.RegisterObjectDefinition(XmlElement element, ParserContext parserContext)
            at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.DefaultXmlObjectDefinitionParser.ParseElement(XmlElement element, ParserContext parserContext)
            at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.DefaultObjectDefinitionDocumentReader.ParseObjectDefinitions(XmlElement root, ObjectDefinitionParserHelper helper)
            at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.DefaultObjectDefinitionDocumentReader.RegisterObjectDefinitions(XmlDocument doc, XmlReaderContext readerContext)
            at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.XmlObjectDefinitionReader.RegisterObjectDefinitions(XmlDocument doc, IResource resource)
            at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.XmlObjectDefinitionReader.DoLoadObjectDefinitions(Stream stream, IResource resource)
       InnerException: Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectDefinitionStoreException
            Message=Error registering object with name 'DomainObjectImplementationClass' defined in 'config' : Object class [ImplementationClass1, SpringDIExample] not found.
<object name="DomainObjectImplementationClass" singleton="false" type="ImplementationClass1, SpringDIExample" xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" />
            Source=Spring.Core
            ObjectName=DomainObjectImplementationClass
            ResourceDescription=config
            StackTrace:
                 at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.XmlReaderContext.ReportException(XmlNode node, String name, String message, Exception cause)
                 at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.DefaultXmlObjectDefinitionParser.ParseObjectDefinition(XmlElement element, String id, ObjectDefinitionParserHelper parserHelper)
                 at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.DefaultXmlObjectDefinitionParser.ParseObjectDefinition(XmlElement element, ParserContext parserContext)
                 at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.DefaultXmlObjectDefinitionParser.RegisterObjectDefinition(XmlElement element, ParserContext parserContext)
            InnerException: System.TypeLoadException
                 Message=Could not load type from string value 'ImplementationClass1, SpringDIExample'.
                 Source=Spring.Core
                 TypeName=""
                 StackTrace:
                      at Spring.Util.TypeResolver.ResolveType(String typeName)
                      at Spring.Util.TypeResolver.Resolve(String typeName)
                      at Spring.Util.CachedTypeResolver.Resolve(String typeName)
                      at Spring.Objects.ObjectUtils.ResolveType(String typeName)
                      at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultObjectDefinitionFactory.CreateObjectDefinition(String typeName, String parent, AppDomain domain)
                      at Spring.Objects.Factory.Xml.DefaultXmlObjectDefinitionParser.ParseObjectDefinition(XmlElement element, String id, ObjectDefinitionParserHelper parserHelper)
                 InnerException: System.TypeLoadException
                      Message=Could not load type 'ImplementationClass1' from assembly 'SpringDIExample, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
                      Source=mscorlib
                      TypeName=ImplementationClass1
                      StackTrace:
                           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
                           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
                           at Spring.Util.TypeResolver.LoadTypeDirectlyFromAssembly(TypeAssemblyInfo typeInfo)
                           at Spring.Util.TypeResolver.ResolveType(String typeName)
                      InnerException:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Note the config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
    <object name="DomainObjectImplementationClass" 
            singleton="false" 
            type="ImplementationClass1, SpringDIExample" />
</objects>
```

Comment: In your config file, you have this line: `<object name="DomainObjectImplementationClass" singleton="false" type="sdd" xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" />`, what is type `sdd`?

Comment: Sorry, that was me playing around. The type is "ImplementationClass1, SpringDIExample". I fixed it, reran it, and reposted the stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: It's always the same message: `type="ImplementationClass1, SpringDIExample"` not recognized. Try `type="SpringDIExample.ImplementationClass1, SpringDIExample"` (class name with the namespace (put the correct one, if it's not `SpringDIExample`)

Comment: Wow!  You got it!  Nice job manji.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I added an answer.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't use DI samples from 2003 today. C# has come a long way, including generics and lambdas so you should use Unity framework, Autofac or similar tools for dependency injection.

Comment: @Dez if manji's answer solves your problem, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try `type="SpringDIExample.ImplementationClass1, SpringDIExample"` (class name with the ***namespace*** (put the correct one, if it's not `SpringDIExample`)

Answer (score 2):

It tells you that it cannot find ImplementationClass1 in your assembly specified.

Check if that class actually exists, spelling, namespace and name of assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to check out Spring.NET new code based configuration model, called CodeConfig, as an alternative to XML.  If you use XML there is also a VS.NET 2010 extension that will catch all those typos and also give you completion for class names and properties.

The main page has links to it - http://www.springframework.net/

The journal http://www.opensource-central.com/ has an article on CodeConfig.

Mark